# Persisting objects with their object identity in Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

How do I persist objects of a class in hibernate without them having an id attribute but using their object identity.

Comment: Why you tag question with `eclipse` tag? Eclipse is IDE. Did you mean `eclipselink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to designate a field that will hold the `@Id` for the entity.

The object identity can't be translated to a database primary key, and a primary key is a requirement.

There's another thing here - the `equals` and `hashcode` methods are usually incorrectly implemented using the `@Id` field. You can use the default implementations which rely on object identity.